# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac {\sin (nx)}{x^2 + n^2} dx = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac {\sin (nx)}{x^2 + n^2} dx=0.$

I think I will use Riemann integrability, but how I do not know, could anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\frac {\sin\, x} {x^{2}+n^{2}}| \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Comment: I will not use the property that the function is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @hopefully You have to use an elementary property of Riemann integrals which says that if $|f(x)| \leq C$ then $|\int_a^{b} f(x)\, dx| \leq C(b-a)$. You can in fact prove this easily from definition of Riemann integral since all Riemann sums have the bound $C(b-a)$.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details about the sequence of steps in proving so .... what should exactly I do?

Comment: @hopefully If $|f(x)| \leq C$ and $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is  partition of $[a,b]$ then the supremum and infimum of $f$ an $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ are also bounded by $C$. Form this you can see that all lower/upper Riemann sums are bounded by $C(b-a)$  (Note that $\sum (x_i-x_{i-1})=b-a$.

Comment: then I will use the hint that you gave me above in the answer?

Comment: @hopefully Yes. the integral is bounded by $\frac {2\pi} {n^{2}}$ so it tends to $0$.

Comment: will I need to take a uniform partition?

Comment: Any partition is fine, but you can choose the uniform partition for definiteness.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But doesn't it suffice in that case observe that $f(x)$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that for $f$ continuous on $(a,b)$

$$\left|{\int_a^b f \left({t}\right) \ \mathrm dt}\right| \le \int_a^b \left|{f \left({t}\right)}\right| \ \mathrm dt$$

therefore we have that

$$0\le \left|\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac {\sin (nx)}{x^2 + n^2} dx\right|\le \frac1{n^2}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac {1}{(x/n)^2 + 1} dx =\frac{1}{n}\arctan\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)$$